# Transform geometry of polygons

Tags: postgis, postgresql, polygon, geometry

I am new to PostGIS.
I'm making a spatial join, but it does not work.
From what I saw it is something of the geometry of polygons.
My polygons are saved with the "Geom" field like this (Geom geometry (Multipolygon) and I need to transform them to the format (Geom geometry (Multipolygon, 4326).
How can it be done?

Answer (score 4):

Two options:

- If your geometries **are defined in EPSG:4326**, you can simply assign the SRID to the column:

  ```
  SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID([<schema>,] <table>, <column>, <SRID>);
  ```

  as a shorthand for

  ```
  ALTER TABLE [<schema>.]<table>
    ALTER COLUMN <column> TYPE GEOMETRY(<GEOM_TYPE>, 4326)
      USING ST_SetSRID(<column>, 4326)
  ;
  ```
- If they **are defined in a different SRID**, you need to transform them:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE [<schema>.]<table>
    ALTER COLUMN <column> TYPE GEOMETRY(<GEOM_TYPE>, 4326)
      USING ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(<column>, <SRID>), 4326)
  ;
  ```